# Show that $U_m(e) = U_m(d)$ where $d = (e, φ(m))$.

Tags: number-theory

Show that $U_m(e) = U_m(d)$ where $d = (e, φ(m))$.

I know that this means $d$ is the $\gcd$ of $e$, and $φ(m)$.And that this is basically the concept of Euler's theorem and Bezout's identity, I'm just unsure how to show it.

Comment: What does $U_m(e)$ mean?

Comment: Um(e) is the set of e-th roots of unity in Um